# iOS - performing animated setContentOffset on UICollectionView slow with ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit

It seems that ARKit takes too much time of the main thread and it causes the animation to be not smooth.

Is there a way to force setContentOffset with high priority?

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying using `commitAnimations` on the `UICollectionView`?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622664-commitanimations

Comment: What do you mean by using commitAnimatinos of UICollectionView. I tried calling UIView.commitAnimations() right after the call to setContentOffset but it did not work